# PrimeNG Turbo Table cell text overflow problem

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, primeng, primeng-turbotable

When using Primeng table and set the table as scrollable the table should show the scrollbar and the text inside the cells should not be overflown. Instead this does not happen.

Check this example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tables-tfbdgt?file=src/app/app.component.html) and resize

Comment: the scrollbar will be shown if you set the scrollHeight for the table e.g scrollHeight="50px"

Comment: check the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tables-tdmjix)

Answer (score 8):

To avoid the text overflow in the cell you can add css style for td

```
td{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

**update :** to show the overflow text in next line

```
td{
word-break:break-all
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I dont want ellipsis to be shown. I need to show text at its full

Comment: you can use word-break:break-all to continue cell value in new line if that is what u need

Comment: I need to show text in same line. The text should be not hidden or overflown.

Comment: you can use [resizable p-table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colresize)

Comment: using this mode the user has to expand by him self the columns. This is not a solution.

Comment: if you went the width of each cell to change based on the value it have i don't think that is possible cause it won't have a grid structure

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#always-responsive

Answer (score 1):

from primeNG ver 7 documents

> Table Layout:
>   . If you require cells to scale based on their contents set autoLayout property to true. Note that Scrollable and/or Resizable tables do not support auto layout due to technical reasons.

[table doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)